# how to return object without create copy of that?

Tags: c++, object, reference, destroy

I develop simple c++ class to testing when c++ objects destroy; now I have a problem, when an object return by function, c++ create a new object and return that and when return reference destroy object what is my mistake ?

simple class attached below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static int freeCounter=0;

class TestCopy {
private:
    string pStr;
public:
    TestCopy(const TestCopy &obj){
        pStr=obj.pStr;
    }
    TestCopy(string &test){
        pStr=test;
    }
    ~TestCopy(){ freeCounter++; cout << freeCounter <<"\t" << pStr << endl; }

    TestCopy get(){
        TestCopy x=*this; 
        return TestCopy(x); // -> TestCopy(x) is first destroy in result
    }

    string getStr(){
        return pStr;
    }
};

int main(){
    string xstr="test";
    TestCopy x(xstr); // x is third destroy
    TestCopy x2=x.get(); // x2 is second destroy

    cout << x.getStr() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and result

```
1   test
test
2   test
3   test
```

Comment: The problem is that none of those `TestCopy`are dynamically allocated, so when the go out of scope they get destroyed.

Comment: You have to explicitly say that you are returning a reference in the function signature `TestCopy& get(){` notice the '&' that I added

Comment: Not quite true, @Rodolfo . Copy elision will take care of the copy construct on return issue and returning a local as a reference is going to blow up in MohsenTi's face because the returned reference isn't going to exist anymore. Moe on copy elision: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization

Comment: `return *this;` would have been the simplest, most efficient way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thank you @seaman with your help I found my mistake.
by changing

```
TestCopy x=*this;
```

with

```
const TestCopy &x=*this;
```

problem solved

Comment: Why do you need `x` when you can just say `return *this;`?

Answer (score 1):

x in function get is a local object, when the function finishes, x will be destroyed.

so, x is the first destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

First a review of OP's code. I've modified it slightly to make what's going on more obvious.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static int allocCounter = 0;

class TestCopy
{
private:
    string pStr;
    int counter;
public:
    TestCopy(const TestCopy &obj)
    {
        allocCounter++;
        counter = allocCounter;
        cout << "copy construct " << counter << endl;
        pStr = obj.pStr;
    }
    TestCopy(const string &test)
    {
        allocCounter++;
        counter = allocCounter;
        cout << "string construct " << counter << endl;
        pStr = test;
    }
    ~TestCopy()
    {
        cout << counter << "\t" << pStr << endl;
    }

    TestCopy get()
    {
        TestCopy x = *this; // copy constructed
        return TestCopy(x); // copy constructed and copy elision
    }

    string getStr()
    {
        return pStr;
    }
    TestCopy & operator=(const TestCopy &obj)
    {
        cout << "assigned " << obj.counter << " to "<< counter << endl;

        pStr = obj.pStr;
//        counter = obj.counter; deliberately left out
        return *this;
    }

};

int main()
{
    string xstr = "test";
    TestCopy x(xstr); // string constructed
    TestCopy x2 = x.get(); // Would be a copy constructed if not for copy elision
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
string construct 1
copy construct 2
copy construct 3
2   test
3   test
1   test
```

Note no calls to the assignment operator even with `TestCopy x=*this;`

Alright. Now how do we chop some of this down?

First we get rid of  a redundant copy in `get`

```
TestCopy get()
{
    return *this; // copy constructed. Or is it? The copy construction could
                  // happen at the caller. Either way it is copied and elided
}
```

Output

```
string construct 1
copy construct 2
2   test
1   test
```

So at this point we know there is no need to copy or assign in get because the return statement will do it for us. This is the important part with respect to OP's question.

But if we change `main` a bit  and add an assignment operator we can observe a bit more interesting behaviour.

```
int main()
{
    string xstr = "test";
    TestCopy x(xstr); // string constructed
    TestCopy x2(""); //string constructed
    x2 = x.get(); // assigned and a copy construct when returning from get
    cout << "done main" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
string construct 1
string construct 2
copy construct 3
assigned 3 to 2
3   test
done main
2   test
1   test
```

The return from `get` was assigned to `x2`, then destroyed. `x2` gets destroyed and finally `x`.